# /etc/shadow and suid dilemma

Tags: linux, shadow, suid

I stumbled on a problem about accessing system files with `suid` executables.

I wrote this short POC:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if (access("/etc/shadow", W_OK) == 0)
        printf("shadow writable!\n");
    else
        printf("shadow not writable\n");

    return 0;
}
```

then i compiled and gave it the suid with `chown root:root` and `chmod u+s`  (ran by root)

this is the resulting executable

```
-rwsrwxr-x  1 root root     4847 Apr 14 08:40 a.out
```

the target file has these rights

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1836 Oct  8  2014 /etc/shadow
```

When I ran the program, it gave this output:

```
[d.berra@srvr ~]$ ./a.out
shadow not writable
```

Why does this happen? I mean... I'm accessing the file as `root` and `root` **CAN** write on this file!

Note: `selinux` is disabled

ideas?

Comment: You should try using `vipw -s` [Best way to edit shadow file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-the-best-way-to-edit-etcpasswd-shadow-and-group-files.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`access`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access):

> The check is done using the calling process's *real* UID and GID, rather than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an operation (e.g., open(2)) on the file. This allows set-user-ID programs to easily determine the invoking user's authority.

So you can successfully open this file for writing, because your effective UID and filesystem UID is now 0, but access will still return error.

As @nos noted, you forgot to change executable owner to `root`:

```
$ sudo chown root:root ./a.out
```

But even if you do that, you wil still get "not writable" due to `access` behavior:

```
$ ls -l ./a.out 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 12651 Apr 14 09:53 ./a.out
$ ./a.out 
shadow not writable
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the suid bit, which means the executable will run as the user owning the executable. The executable will run as `d.berra`, which can't write to `/etc/shadow`.

If you want the executable to run as root regardless of the user that runs it, the executable should be owned by root in addition to setting the suid bit.

Comment: It will still print `shadow not writable!` even if you change user to root.

Comment: the purpose of suid bit is to run the executable as root as effective user. Otherwise there's not difference with an executable with no suid bit set

Comment: @DavideBerra: the purpose of suid is to replace effective ID with the _owner_ of executable -- it may not be root.

Comment: I think you should emphasize word "owning". That's the crux of suid.

Comment: yes sorry... i forgot to chown root:root the exec... btw it doesn't work though

Comment: @DavideBerra That's because access() uses different rules when running a setuid executable, as myaut notes. You could use open("/etc/shadow", O_RDWR) instead, which will perform the access checks using the effective IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setuid(0);

    if (access("/etc/shadow", W_OK) == 0)
        printf("shadow writable!\n");
    else
        printf("shadow not writable\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It sets the user ID to root to be able to access the file. setuid(0) only works in case the effective user ID is also 0.